# Adding a new record invalid arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I've done this before in VS2010 and it worked fine, now in VS2012, I'm getting told I have invalid arguments on `ne.posts.Add(post)`. In VS2010, the method was called **AddObject()**

```
myDataModel.post post = new myDataModel.post();

post.postauthor = author;
post.postdate = DateTime.Now;
post.postmessage = msg;

// ne is the DbContext generated from the database
ne.posts.Add(post);
ne.SaveChanges();
```

The `posts` entity doesn't have an AddObject method here so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For linq2sql, you need:

```
ne.posts.insertOnSubmit(post);
ne.SubmitChanges();
```

With entity framework, you use:

```
ne.posts.AddObject(post);
ne.SaveChanges();
```

Take a look here for the different ways to add records...http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=619

```
1. Use ObjectSet<TEntity>.AddObject() 
2. Use ObjectContext.AddObject() 
3. Use EntityCollection<TEntity>.Add()
```

So, I suspect you've added Linq2Sql to the project instead of entity framework model.

Comment: Those methods don't seem to exist either :/ think I did something wrong setting up the data model

Comment: Does the designer object have .emdx or .dbml?

Comment: got a .edmx file in my solution explorer there

Comment: Do you have AddToPosts?

Comment: I don't... I do have SaveChanges() though

Comment: Well, it took a few trashed projects, but I finally got my linq2sql working again. Just had to recreate the project a few times